# Invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'A'

Tags: c++

Why does this small example:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void run() override {
        std::cout << "Running...\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<A>(new B());
}
```

Gives me this error message:

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'A'
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
because the following virtual functions are pure within 'A':
 class A {
'virtual void A::run()'
     virtual void run() = 0;
```

Is this because a unique_ptr cannot take an abstract class as argument?

Comment: `Is this because a unique_ptr cannot take an abstract class as argument?` It can, but `make_unique` can't. `std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();`.

Comment: Missing virtual destructor BTW.

Answer (score 8):

> Why does this small example: ... Gives me this error message: `invalid new-expression of abstract`
>
> Is this because a unique_ptr cannot take an abstract class as argument?

No, it isn't. `std::unique_ptr` can take an abstract class as an argument.

It is because you're attempting to create an instance of `A`. This is not possible because `A` is abstract.

You may have intended instead to create an instance of `B`, and have the `std::unique_ptr<A>` take ownership of that pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();
```

Note though however, that you mustn't let this pointer go out of scope, because upon destruction of `a`, the object would be deleted through a pointer to `A`, and since the pointed object is `B`, and destructor of `A` is not virtual, the behaviour would be undefined. Solution: declare `A::~A` virtual.